# How can I make Org mode's capture functionality accept tags starting with '%'?

Tags: org-capture

I use org mode and its capture functionality for capturing notes and tasks on the go. My capture code looks like this:

```
(setq org-capture-templates '((
     "n"                                ; key
     "Make a note in p.abc.org "        ; description
     entry                              ; type
     (file+headline "p.abc.org" "logg") ; target
     "* %^{Note} :NOTE:          \n%?"  ; template
     :prepend t                         ; properties
     :empty-lines 1                     ; properties )))
```

This produces a note headline with the tagg "NOTE" if I call the function with `C-c c n`

The problem arises if I want to use a taggs starting with a "%" sign. Hence, if I change the template line above to

```
"* %^{Note} :%NOTE:          \n%?"  ; template
```

I get the following error message: `"Capture abort: (void-variable v-N)"`

Can I change the code to make capture accept `%` signs in the beginning of tags?

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try escaping the `%` with a backslash.

Comment: Thanks :) i will try that..like " :/%NOTE: ?

Comment: Hi Dan , it did not work, neither " :/%NOTE: " , nor ":\%NOTE:", both variants gave the original error message.

Comment: You would need at least double backslash because of string read-syntax: `":\\%NOTE:"`.

Comment: Double backlash worked. Thanks til both of you !